# Book Proof Problem - nth roots of unity are of the form $z=\text{cis}(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, cyclic-groups

So I found this theorem and proof in my abstract algebra book in the section about cyclic groups. Here it goes:

> Theorem: If $z^n=1$, then the nth roots of unity are 
>   $$z=\text{cis}(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$$where $k\in \mathbb Z^{+}.$
>
> Proof: DeMoivre's Theorem. $$z^n=\text{cis}(n\frac{2k\pi}{n})=\text{cis}(2k\pi)=1$$

My issue: the assumption is already made in the proof that $|z|=r=1$, because DeMoivre's Theorem states that $z^n=r^n\text{cis}(n\theta)$, so $r^n=1$ for this to work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: By definition $r \geq 0$, so this is going to work. Another proof would be using the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: You are correct, we need to show that $|z|=1$, which we do using the identity $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$.

Comment: Isn't the proof showing that a complex number of the form $\text{cis}(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$ satisfies $z^n = 1,$ thus they are the nth roots of unity (defined to be the complex numbers st $z^n=1$)? We know there are $n$ such numbers, and by the fundamental theorem of algebra, we know there are $n$ roots, so we are done.

Comment: @Slade can you please expand on that?

Comment: @SalmonKiller $|\operatorname{cis}(t)|^2 = |\cos{t} + i\sin{t}|^2 = \cos^2{t} + \sin^2{t}$.

Comment: @Slade i get that, but we never assumed that $z \in \mathbb T$.

Comment: @SalmonKiller So?  My last comment is a proof that $z\in\mathbb{T}$.  The definition of $z$ is $\cos{t} + i \sin{t}$ (for $t=\frac{2k\pi}{n}$), and we compute the square of the modulus by summing the squares of the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @Slade I think that we are only allowed to assume that $z^n=1$. In your first comment, you assumed that $r=1$. In other words, it's circular reasoning as I see it.

Comment: @SalmonKiller You're confused.  We assume that $z=\operatorname{cis} (\frac{2k\pi}{n})$.  The goal is to prove that $z^n=1$, which we do using De Moivre's Theorem.  You had the reasonable complaint that De Moivre's Theorem (one version of it, anyway) has a factor of $r^n$.  In order to get rid of this factor, we must prove that $r=1$.  But $r$ is defined to be the complex modulus $|z|$, which we can calculate directly, as I showed you, to be $1$.

Comment: @SalmonKiller I am making some guesses about your book, since you don't mention what book it is.  There is something strange about the phrasing... we could also assume $z^n=1$, and try to conclude that $z=\operatorname{cis}(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$ for some $k$, but this requires an entirely different approach than the one described.  To do this, we should assume that $z=r\operatorname{cis} t$ for some $t$, then solve for $r$ and $t$ using De Moivre.